# Closing input tag issue in xhtml

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have closed all the possible tags here in my xhtml document that also includes few scripting part and yet I'm receiving the close input tag issue. Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Assignment3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="tick" onclick="addCostApple()"/>apple<br/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="tick" onclick="addCostOrange()"/>banana<br/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="tick" onclick="addCostBanana()"/>cherry<br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="displayCost()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var total=0;
        function addCostApple()
        {
             total = total + 59;
        }
        function addCostOrange()
        {
             total = total + 49;
        }
        function addCostBanana()
        {
             total = total + 39;
        }
        function displayCost()
        {
            var tax = (0.05*total)/100;
            alert("Cost : $ "+(total/100)+"\nTax : $"+tax+"\nTotal : $"+(total+tax)/100);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the error I'm getting :

```
    XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </input>. Location: 
file:///home/aravind/aravind/Sessions/Web%20programming/JavaScript
/day2/Assignment3.xhtml Line Number 35, Column 3:
```

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="displayCost()" --/-->`

Comment: xml tag is not closed

Comment: 2 times `<html>`

Comment: Ya I corrected that extra html tag, still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Is it the console or some where else?
As far as my knowledge, input doesn't need a closing tag.

Comment: Yes I understand your frustration, I was introduced to javascript yesterday, of course it will be horrible and I'm trying to learn. And thanks for your valuable feedback.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XHTML you have to close all HTML tags. The browser will translate it as HTML without `<input>` close tag.

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp) the syntax XHTML rules.